# In SSMS, is "Navigate to" (Ctrl+,) of any use?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In standard Visual Studio 2012 or higher, IDE window called *Navigate to...* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) offers all useful objects in scope of currently open project (see [samples](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20studio%20navigate%20to&tbm=isch)) getting increasingly filtered as I am **typing** so I can quickly navigate to what I need without expanding the tree with hundreds of items.

The same *Navigate to...* I can find in *SQL Server Management Studio 2014* (perhaps since SSMS 2012?) but as I type, I can see only some backup files in SSMS `%TEMP%` directory. Is this everything what can be get from *Navigate to...*?

I would like to see it offering me names of tables, stored procedures and SQL functions etc. so I can jump to them in *Object Explorer* or view their definition. **Any tricks to make *Navigate to...* more useful in the SSMS?**

(Currently I have SSMS 2014 connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2.)

**Note:** I'm aware of various ways of navigating in SSMS, but now I would like to learn more about *Navigate to...* which is convenient typing-oriented  search&go tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **In SSMS 2016, *Navigate To...* is gone.**

So **the answer is** that temporary presence of non-functioning *Navigate To...* feature in SSMS 2014 looks like forgotten artifact of adopting SSMS to Visual Studio platform. Perhaps we should seek nothing more serious behind it.

Comment: SSMS 2016 seems to be much more polished, it fixes many weird technical and design errors seen in SSMS 2014, including non-standard keyboard shortcuts. After leaving good SSMS 2008 and 3-of-5-stars experience with SSMS 2014 I recommend installing [standalone SSMS 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), which can get 4.5. They even can be installed and used side-by-side, if someone is hesitant to uninstall that 2014 thing on the first day. So far, I found only [one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37876115/2392157) with SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I am using SSMS 2018 and "Navigate to..." using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> is certainly there (still there/back). I don't know what it does, though.

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators. Please, wait until you have enough reputation to add comments, don't post them as answers to the question.

Comment: I'm using a recent/latest Win 10 version (v18.9.1), Ctrl+, does open a Go to All window, but it is pretty much useless. Best you can do is search your AppData folder from what I can see.